# Using Environ$(“USERPROFILE”) VBA save to path

Tags: vba, excel, environ

I am new to VBA, so apologies for my ignorance.
I have a very complicated macro in Excel 2016 that I need to edit.
It is related to [this previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316486/export-data-from-excel-to-pdf-form-without-saving-it-as-csv-or-other-file-first?noredirect=1#comment81584538_47316486)

I need to change the output save path of a created .pdf. Right now it is using the Excel location as a starting point, (ThisWorkbook.Path) and was saved into that same folder.

But now it needs to save to a different folder which will be on a shared Box drive. The path will change depending on who is accessing the file.

So how should I use Environ$ to indicate that **C:\Users\johnsmith**\Box\etc. etc.  will change and everything after \Box\etc. etc. is constant?
It is using values from the Excel spreadsheet to make up the new file name.

Here's the bit I need to edit:

```
With shDetail
        If llRow - 3 < 10 Then
            strPDFOutPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2018 Payments\0" & .Cells(llRow, 14).Value & "_" & .Cells(llRow, 3).Value & "_" & "file" & ".pdf"
        Else
            strPDFOutPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2018 Payments\" & .Cells(llRow, 14).Value & "_" & .Cells(llRow, 3).Value & "_" & "file" & ".pdf"
        End If
    End With

    'Save the form as new PDF file.
    objAcroPDDoc.Save 1, strPDFOutPath
```

So should it be

```
 strPDFOutPath = Environ$(“USERPROFILE”) & Box\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\0" & .Cells(llRow, 14).Value & "_" & .Cells(llRow, 3).Value & "_" & "file" & ".pdf"
        Else
            strPDFOutPath = Environ$(“USERPROFILE”) & Box\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3" & .Cells(llRow, 14).Value & "_" & .Cells(llRow, 3).Value & "_" & "file" & ".pdf"
```

?

Comment: User = Environ$("UserName"), gets username of person/machine running code

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example of what it could look like:

```
    Const FILE_SUFFIX As String = "\Box\Etc\Whatever\"
    Dim userPath As String

    userPath = Environ("UserProfile")

    strPDFOutPath  = userPath & FILE_SUFFIX & & .Cells(llRow, 14).Value & "_" & .Cells(llRow, 3).Value & "_" & "file" & ".pdf"
```