# Error when Printing to PDF with excel macros. Will only work with actual Adobe and not Adobe Reader

Tags: vba, excel, pdf-generation

I have this Excel sheet that consolidates a bunch of reports and prints them to PDF.  The code works fine when I was on a pc that had the actual Adobe software installed.  I tried using it on my personal lap top which only has a adobe reader and the macros crashed with:

```
Sub JoinPDFFile(strPDFToLocation As String, strPDFTo As String, _
 strPDFFromLocation As String, strPDFFrom As String)



  Dim objAcroExchApp As Object
  Dim objAcroExchNewPDDoc As Object
  Dim objAcroExchExistPDDoc As Object
  Dim intLastPage As Integer
  Dim intNewPages As Integer


  Set objAcroExchApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App") <---This is the error
  'New PDF document object
  Set objAcroExchApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
  If Dir(strPDFToLocation & strPDFTo & ".pdf") = strPDFTo & ".pdf" Then
    objAcroExchApp.Open strPDFToLocation & strPDFTo & ".pdf"
   Else
    objAcroExchApp.Create
  End If
```

Where it says Set objAcroExchApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App") <---This is the error

So I was wondering.  Would I have to go back and change everything in the code so that it works with whatever PDF file reader the current user has?

I tried using On Error Resume Next above that and all it did was forgo the entire process and just print the first page when there was supposed to be 20 pages.

Is there a way to just simply the entire code just so that it makes a PDF file and not be contingent upon whether I have Adobe?  So even if you use Foxit, Dejvu, etc.. it still works?

Comment: What is the error message? Do you try to run as administrator?

Comment: @Portekoi the error is Run-Time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.  It does not matter about running as an administrator.  This error happens if I'm using Adobe Reader and not actual Adobe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel does not require any specific library to be there for it to `ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF` but to use
AcroExch.App Adobe Pro is required. So it really depends on what you want to do with the PDF (it is not clear from your code, I guess it is not just open or create), to do certain things Adobe Pro might be better suited, another might do certain things better, etc. 
For example, [BYTESCOUT](https://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html) SDK are powerful, easy to use and support multiple functionality and If I need to create CSV from PDF I can do it by adding 3 lines
in your code:

```
Sub JoinPDFFile(strPDFToLocation As String, strPDFTo As String, _
 strPDFFromLocation As String, strPDFFrom As String)

  Dim objAcroExchApp As Object
  Dim objAcroExchNewPDDoc As Object
  Dim objAcroExchExistPDDoc As Object
  Dim intLastPage As Integer
  Dim intNewPages As Integer
  Dim extractor As New Bytescout_PDFExtractor.CSVExtractor


  'Set objAcroExchApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App") '<---This is the error
  'New PDF document object
  'Set objAcroExchApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

  If Dir(strPDFToLocation & strPDFTo & ".pdf") = strPDFTo & ".pdf" Then
    'objAcroExchApp.Open strPDFToLocation & strPDFTo & ".pdf"
    extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile strPDFToLocation & strPDFTo & ".pdf"
    extractor.SaveCSVToFile (strPDFToLocation & strPDFTo & ".csv")
   Else
    'objAcroExchApp.Create
  End If

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A reply here : 
[VBA: Acrobat Run time error 429; ActiveX component can't create object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677288/vba-acrobat-run-time-error-429-activex-component-cant-create-object?rq=1)

`This OLE interface is available with Adobe Acrobat, not Adobe Reader.`

EDIT

Try to create a Macro and test this. It works for me. (only `xls` file)

```
Sub PDF()

Dim sPDFFileName As String

sPDFFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Essai.pdf"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets(Array("Sheet1")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sPDFFileName _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so basically the solution is to have Adobe Acrobat and not Adobe Reader.  I know that, so I'm asking if there's a way to change the code so that it moves on from that and it opens/reads with whatever PDF reader you have on your system?

Comment: Try PDFCreator. I've made tests there is a long time but it was working.

Comment: Test my macro and tell me

Comment: omg dude my bad, I didn't see that you wrote a macro in your comment.  I'll try it right now