# unable to create Acrobat.AcroPDDoc object in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat-sdk

I am exporting the pdf to excel, but some how I am unable to create the object for Acrobat.AcroPDDoc in my vba code

[image: imported reference the below mentioned lib]

my vba code in

```
Dim AC_PD As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc              'access pdf file
Dim AC_Hi As Acrobat.AcroHiliteList         'set selection word count
Dim AC_PG As Acrobat.AcroPDPage             'get the particular page
Dim AC_PGTxt As Acrobat.AcroPDTextSelect    'get the text of selection area

Dim WS_PDF As Worksheet
Dim RW_Ct As Long                           'row count
Dim Col_Num As Integer                      'column count
Dim Li_Row As Long                          'Maximum rows limit for one column
Dim Yes_Fir As Boolean                      'to identify beginning of page

Li_Row = Rows.Count


Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Set AC_Hi = New Acrobat.AcroHiliteList
```

while creating the new object  for AC_PD it show unable to create ActivX component can't Object how to resolved this issue.
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Is it the `set` line? Is the prefix `acrobat` correct?  Do you have the correct licence etc to do this?  I've done this in the past, the documentation is hard to find and very sketchy, but i'll try and dig it out and put the link on here.

Comment: yes name is correct as it was generated via lib & i am using adobe dc free verssion

Comment: thank you for this

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: yes it compile csucessfully

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678770/4088852).

Answer (score 2):

To create an Acro-object you have to use AcroExch.
So use: 
Set AC_PD = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc").
You will find many, many more examples on this site.
All will work, if you have the full Adobe Acrobat version (not Reader only)